# Calculated field with forecasting data on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, forecasting

It is possible to put the forecasting data into a table, so you can work with them?

I need to show a number of how far our sales are from the tableau forecast, not just the graph.

**UPDATE**

I have two rows of data.

```
- PAST_DATA (2013 - 2014)
- CURRENT_DATA (2015)
```

I need to forecasting the past data and then compare the forecast data with the current data to calculate the difference. It this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go Worksheet > Copy > Crosstab and paste it into excel. You'll have the forecasting figures.

Or if you want to see it in a table in tableau, click Show Me and select text table. 
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. But it is possible to see it as a Table on Tableau?

Comment: Now I get it, I was not able to see this because I have 2 rows of data. row 1 PAST DATA: from Jan 2013 to Dec 2014. and row 2 CURRENT DATA from Jan 2015 to Sep 2015... I wanted to forecast the past data and then compare the result with the current data, and then saw how far we are from the forecast... I'm going to update the question, thank you anyway